# How to keep the imprisonment of mythical creatures a secret from the public, but not from their human family members?

Tags: magic, humans, alternate-earth, secret-society, law-enforcement

For longer than has been recorded, "monster hunters" of various denominations have hunted humanoid magical creatures which have lived in hiding for even longer.

Most of these creatures can each morph into one species of animal, and in addition, have magical powers that fit into 1-3 categories per individual. These magical abilities and related features are usually hereditary, but may spontaneously occur. Magical abilities do not manifest until adolescence, but other features such as tails or fangs are present from birth. Abilities can be in any of a wide range of magic from controlling the weather to changing the chemical makeup of a substance, but mind-control by magical means does not exist in this universe.

The majority of hunters throughout history claim that the creatures are an affront to their God, though how they think it works varies from the idea that using magic at all is a sin to the belief that the creatures are subhuman and demonic in nature.

These creatures are as diverse if not more so than humans in ideology and moral alignment, but most are not more of a threat to others than they would be if they were human.

In the early 1930s, the hunters reach out to the USA's federal government with information on the creatures and claims that they are a threat to humanity. Magic is still a secret, but the hunters are getting bolder and more numerous. Not long after, magical creatures implore the government for protection. They are offered land in each state where they can live apart from humanity as a community that can use magic with relative freedom. This promise is accepted by all parties and kept with the condition that the creatures cannot leave, must report the development of their powers to the government, cannot drive automobiles or own firearms, cannot hold public office, and are policed mainly by humans armed with swords and crossbows.

In the early 2010s, creatures who have not been reached by this offer are still being discovered, including those who have married or been born to humans. These creatures must relocate to the land the government has restricted them to whether they like it or not.

How do the people who are in charge of keeping the creatures imprisoned and secret handle human relatives and associates of these creatures who know about magic, but may not cooperate and have too many ties to the outside world to imprison them inconspicuously? What could the procedures be for a human parent or guardian of a minor with magical powers?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how common these "creatures among humans" are, either the government have to...:

1. Rare : ...do nothing. Who would belive them anyways. People claiming that their daughter was born with fangs and promptly deported by federal agents would have the same rank as those abducted and probed by aliens.
2. Unusual: ... discredit anyone claiming they know or knew "monster people". Just pressure their doctor into adding a "mental health assessment" to the files regarding that person. Also they can reduce the number of people spilling the beans by offering monetary incentives to keep shut. Especially when they already saw others being rediculed over speaking up, most people are more willing to take money instead of speaking up and becoming rediculed as well.
3. Common: ... do nothing. No way to keep things tight when everybody knows someone who has had their family members abducted by the government. In this case the focus should instead be propaganda to frame the "monster people" as inherintly evil and dangerous. If done effective even relatives will often report newborns with tails as to "protect" the parents.

Comment: The creatures are definitely uncommon, but I don't think that the government pressuring doctors to deem  certain people mentally incompetent would do much more than make the doctors question what is going on too.

Comment: A lot of doctors will need to be in on this anyway, as they will see those fang and tail bearing children at birth or in ultrasonic during pregnancy.

Answer (score 1):

You've gone to the effort of setting up an oppressive regime, just take the next logical step.

If someone crosses an oppressive regime, they disappear. The family largely know what has happened to them because that's what happens to everyone who's disappeared. Sometimes they reappear again, but more often than not, that's the last you'll hear of them. Children in other regimes also disappear, never to been seen or heard from again.

Conspiracies will flare up, encourage them, they make sensible people hesitate to avoid association. Avoid any suggestions there may be a serial killer as that causes panic. Make sure any normal runaways are publicly reunited so that anyone else who disappears could be suggested to have run away. Teenagers will sometimes run away after all.